# Multiple requests with nuxt-axios

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs

I have configured a plugin for my `axios` requests.

In `onRequest` method I make request loading property true and in `onResponse` I make it false.

My challenge is when I want to send multiple requests together, but on each request the property "`request_loading`" is toggling until the last request. I want to check if all the requests are done to set "`request_loading`" false.

How should I have a configuration to **handle** **multi requests**?

*Thanks for any recommendations.*

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your multiple requests in `Promise.all()`. Put all your requests in an array like:

```
const reqs = [req1, req2, req3];
```

Then pass that array to a `Promise.all()` like this:

```
async apiCalls() {
  const reqs = [req1, req2, req3];
  const response = await Promise.all(reqs);
  // the response would be an array with each element being the response of the
     requset like [res1, res2, res3]
  ...
};
```

This way multiple requests act as a single request, therefore toggle the loading when all of them are resolved.

You can use this method only if your requests do not depend on each other (i.e. they can be called in parallel that is `req2` does not use the `req1` response and so on).

Comment: I did it, but each of them are going through onRequest method of nuxt-module in axios.js in plugins and they are behaving as seperated requests. `Promise.all([this.$axios({name: 'testApi'}), this.$axios({name: 'testApi2'}), this.$axios({name: 'testApi3'})]);`

Answer (score 0):

It is a feature to be added to `@nuxtjs/axios` plugin which is missing, I did id with `axios.all` method.